# How to export certificate in PEM format?

Tags: ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, starttls

I have an Ubuntu LDAP server, with STARTTLS using a self-signed certificate (following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-tls)).

When setting up a CentOS client (following [these instructions](http://www.certdepot.net/ldap-configure-a-system-to-use-an-existing-ldap-service-for-user-connection/)), the `authconfig-tui` command asks me for the certificate in PEM format:

```
│ To connect to a LDAP server with TLS       │
│ protocol enabled you need a CA certificate │
│ which signed your server's certificate.    │
│ Copy the certificate in the PEM format to  │
│ the '/etc/openldap/cacerts' directory.     │
│ Then press OK.                             │
```

How do I get the certificate in PEM format? I found these command, but the `/etc/dirsrv/` folder does not even exist on my ubuntu system.

```
certutil -L -d /etc/dirsrv/slapd-SOMETHING
certutil -L -d /etc/dirsrv/slapd-SOMETHING -n "SOMETHING_ELSE" -a > cacert.asc
```

I have also seen the command `certutil -L -d /etc/openldap/certs`, which gives me this error message (I have also tried with `/etc/ssl/certs`):

```
certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format.
```

Note that for obvious reasons, I would like to export only the public part of the certificate, not the private part (being used to the easy-to-recognize SSH keys, where id_rsa is private and id_rsa.pub is public, I always find it difficult to know if a certificate I exported is public or private…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the instructions you linked to, then you've got the certificate in PEM format already. From these instructions:

```
Create the self-signed CA certificate:

sudo certtool --generate-self-signed \
   --load-privkey /etc/ssl/private/cakey.pem \ 
   --template /etc/ssl/ca.info \
   --outfile /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

The certificate is `/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` and it is in PEM format.

> ...I would like to export only the public part of the certificate, not the private part

A certificate (`cacert.pem`) contains only the public key. The private key (`cakey.pem`) is not included in the certificate.

Comment: After copying that file in the requested directory, I get the following error when connecting with ldapsearch -x -ZZ: `ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
 additional info: TLS error -8157:Certificate extension not found.`, so I must have done something else wrong. Thanks anyway :) .

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without seeing your certificate.